# Do I dispose the object?

Tags: dispose

I have been using SPDisposeChecker & reading through http://blogs.msdn.com/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx but there are some conditions I am unsure of..

1. I believe this has become ok and the web is disposed with the paerent SPSite

   ```
    using( SPSite mySite = new SPSite("...")){
         SPWeb rootWeb = mySite.RootWeb;
         ...
    }
   ```
2. I think I need to dispose this because it uses open web but not sure since its created with SPContext

   ```
   SPWeb myWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("myWebUrl");
   ```
3. Very confident I should here

   ```
   UserProfile profile = ProfileLoader.GetProfileLoader().GetUserProfile();
   SPSite mySite = profile.PersonalSite;
   ```

How can I execute code & measure if there is a leak? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reading through the [MSDN Disposing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557362%28v=office.14%29.aspx) wiki? It explains how and when to dispose the various objects.

> This article serves as a guide to the proper procedures for handling
>   and disposing of SharePoint objects that implement IDispose. The
>   issues discussed in this article are also flagged by the SharePoint
>   Dispose Checker Tool, a free program available as a download that
>   inspects your assemblies for coding practices that cause memory leaks
>   because of improper handling and disposal of SharePoint objects.

Answer (score -1):

1. When you access the `RootWeb` of an `SPSite` object, it's the same thing as doing `site.OpenWeb()`, so you need to dispose of that web object. I'm not sure it gets disposed with the parent so I always explicitly call the dispose method.
2. You're opening the web object so you need to close it (dispose)
3. You're right, you need to dispose of that `SPSite` too.

The rule of thumb is, when you open the object you close it, or in a more formal way, when you're the one creating the instance of that object you need to dispose it.

The clear exceptions are the `.Web` and `.Site` of the current context.

You can check the ULS logs and SharePoint will tell you if you left `SPSite` and `SPWeb` objects to be disposed. Like this:

> An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.

I've also seen this:

> Potentially excessive number of SPRequest objects (107)

Fortunately, it wasn't my code... ;)

You should also use the developer dashboard, it will show you lots if relevant information.

Comment: Do not explicitly call Dispose() on the SPSite.RootWeb property.  The dispose cleanup will be handled automatically by the SharePoint and the .NET framework.